# Does piecewise continuity of $f'$ implies that the discontinuities of $f$ are jump discontinuities?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-series, continuity, piecewise-continuity

In [this pdf](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_15.pdf), the following theorem is stated without proof:

[image]

I'm not sure how this mathematically is accurate. My question is:

Do the limits $f(x^+)$ and $f(x^-)$ exist, in the last statement? i.e. Does piecewise continuity of $f'$ implies that the discontinuities of $f$ are jump discontinuities?

Comment: No.  Take $$f(x):= \begin{cases} |x| & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\ 57 & \text{if $x=0$} \end{cases}$$  (If you want an $f$ that exactly fits your problem, take $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-L,L]$ and periodicize it!)

Comment: @Dzoooks yes, but my main question is the existence of limits. This is why I called it jump discontinuity.

Comment: I guess this is part of the definition of "piecewise continuous".

Comment: As @WimC said, the piecewise continuity of $f$ implies that the one-sided limits exist.